# Mockito. No argument value was captured

Tags: java, unit-testing, mockito

How this code should be changed so that it does not throw below exception?

```
ArgumentCaptor<Date> argument = forClass(Date.class);
verify(ps, times(0)).setDate(anyInt(), argument.capture());

typeHandler.setNonNullParameter(ps, 1, "20170120", DATE);

assertEquals(new Date(2017, 01, 20), argument.getValue());
```

More code:

```
import org.apache.ibatis.type.BaseTypeHandler;
import org.apache.ibatis.type.JdbcType;
import org.joda.time.LocalDate;
import org.joda.time.format.DateTimeFormat;
import org.joda.time.format.DateTimeFormatter;

import java.sql.*;

public class DateStringTypeHandler extends BaseTypeHandler<String> {

    private static final DateTimeFormatter YYYY_MM_DD = DateTimeFormat.forPattern("yyyyMMdd");

    @Override
    public void setNonNullParameter(PreparedStatement ps, int i, String parameter, JdbcType jdbcType) throws SQLException {
        LocalDate localDate = YYYY_MM_DD.parseLocalDate(parameter);
        ps.setDate(i, new Date(localDate.toDateTimeAtStartOfDay().getMillis()));
    }
}

@RunWith(MockitoJUnitRunner.class)
public class DateStringTypeHandlerTest {

    @Mock
    private PreparedStatement ps;
    private DateStringTypeHandler typeHandler;

    @Before
    public void before() {
        typeHandler = new DateStringTypeHandler();
    }

    @Test
    public void testSetNonNullParameterPreparedStatementIntStringJdbcType() throws SQLException {
        ArgumentCaptor<Date> argument = forClass(Date.class);
        verify(ps, times(0)).setDate(anyInt(), argument.capture());

        typeHandler.setNonNullParameter(ps, 1, "20170120", DATE);

        assertEquals(new Date(2017, 01, 20), argument.getValue());
    }
}
```

`verify` throws exception:

```
org.mockito.exceptions.base.MockitoException: 
No argument value was captured!
You might have forgotten to use argument.capture() in verify()...
...or you used capture() in stubbing but stubbed method was not called.
Be aware that it is recommended to use capture() only with verify()

Examples of correct argument capturing:
    ArgumentCaptor<Person> argument = ArgumentCaptor.forClass(Person.class);
    verify(mock).doSomething(argument.capture());
    assertEquals("John", argument.getValue().getName());
```

Comment: If you just verified that something happened zero times, how can you expect to have captured its argument?

Comment: zero times in workaround, it should be removed, but it throws another exception if removed. Something is used wrong, but I can't figure out what and how to use it right

Comment: But the method hasn't been called. That's what `verify(..., times(0))` is verifying. So there isn't any captured argument for you to get.

Comment: if you put a breakpoint to setNonNullParameter, you'll see that method is called

Comment: You didnt invoke the method testSetNonNullParameterPreparedStatementIntStringJdbcType(). Modify  your test method and call typeHandler. testSetNonNullParameterPreparedStatementIntStringJdbcType()

Comment: method testSetNonNullParameterPreparedStatementIntStringJdbcType is invoked by test runner, what are you talking about?

Comment: If you add any variation of times() to the verify call, the argument will not be captured because potentially the call could have been made multiple times. Strange that nobody else noticed that :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should invoke the method of the class under test first. Then you verify using the captor:

```
    @Test
    public void testSetNonNullParameterPreparedStatementIntStringJdbcType() throws SQLException {
        // Arrange
        ArgumentCaptor<Date> argument = forClass(Date.class);

        // Act
        typeHandler.setNonNullParameter(ps, 1, "20170120", DATE);

        // Assert            
        verify(ps).setDate(anyInt(), argument.capture());    
        assertEquals(new Date(2017, 01, 20), argument.getValue());
    }
```

Also now you probably would not need the `times(..)` argument.

Comment: thanks, works for me. I thought (exaples promote) that argument capture must be initialised first.

Comment: If you specify any times() variation with capture it fails to work, this needs to be stated more clearly as it was the problem.

Answer (score 0):

I was having the same issue. when I debugged it, the issue turned out that as the debugger goes out of the function, the local scope of the captor declared inside the function diminishes and so I got error.

Try creating/declaring the captor variable inside the class outside of the function. It works!

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).